# WPF Force specific visual to be render in software mode only

Tags: wpf

I am working with WPF and wonder if there is any way to force a specific visual to be rendered in software mode only.

For example, there few Rectangle inside a grid:

```
Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle() { Width = ........};
Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle() .........
......... rect3 .....
     .... rect4 ......
```

I want rect1 to be rendered in software mode and the others rectangles (rect2,3,4) to be rendered with hardware acceleration.

Is it possible to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can, why you need this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can force software rendering at the window or application level, but not for specific elements within the same container. This makes sense when you consider how elements are composited together by the WPF layout system and rendered from that composite state. Think about what would happen if they're overlapped, partially transparent, etc. Mixing modes requires jumping out of the layout system with separate Hwnds that would then have rendering managed at the OS level.

For reference, application level software rendering can be set with:

```
RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
```

And individual windows (Hwnds) can set with:

```
HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(myVisual) as HwndSource;
HwndTarget target = source.CompositionTarget;
target.RenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
```